# postgres read query resample time series data for hourly averages

Tags: postgresql, python, timescaledb

I am new to SQL trying to learn how to do read queries on time series data. Can someone give me a tip on how to resample interval time series data to hourly averages on the postgres read query?

My table is named building_data where there are a few columns named `time, metric, value, kv_tags, m_tags`

`time` is my date/time stamp column where I am trying to see if I can resample the data in the `value` column into hourly averages. The `WHERE` in the query below is to filter out for a specific device that I am interested in looking at the data. I apologize if that doesn't make sense.

For a first timer this sql query appears to work but its not incorporating some process to resample the data in hourly averages, any tips greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
  "time" AS "time",
  metric AS metric,
  value,
  kv_tags,
  m_tags
FROM building_data
WHERE kv_tags->'equip_name' = '["35201"]' AND 
  m_tags IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY time desc limit 1000
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! A word of advice - don't use [SQL keywords](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) (i.e. **time** & **hour**) as column or field names... it's potentially confusing and makes debugging difficult...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [time_bucket](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/simplified-time-series-analytics-using-the-time_bucket-function/) function to make it.

Example:

```sql
SELECT
  time_bucket('1 hour', "time") AS hour,
  metric,
  avg(value)
FROM building_data
WHERE kv_tags->'equip_name' = '["35201"]' AND 
  m_tags IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY hour, metric
ORDER BY hour limit 1000
```

Note that I'm simplifying the query and if you want to include `kv_tags` and `m_tags` you'll need to also use aggregation functions or add them to the group by clause.